# Azure face transactions and limits using containers provided by cognitive services

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-cognitive-services

1. If I use Azure face for verification using a container image with servers on my premises, do I still need to abide by the TPS limits?
2. If I use the face web API hosted by Microsoft, as face verification needs faceId from Face-Detect. Does that verification take 2 transactions? Does the same apply for Azure Face hosted on my server using the face container?

Answer (score 0):

The TPS limits of the cloud API do not apply to the container; this is one of the reasons Microsoft offers the option for you to host the service.  Your TPS limit is bound by how much compute resources you allocate to your container(s).

The transaction counting for cloud and container services are the same.  As you've noted, face verification will take two transactions, one to generate the face ID, and another to compute the match.